# How to bundle both js & ts files at the same time using gulp browserify?

Tags: typescript, gulp, bundle, browserify, typescript-typings

I got a small javascript file (common.js) that needs to be bundled with the compiled typescript files using gulp browserify.
Where shall I specify the common.js in gulpfile.js?

Currently my gulpfile.js is as below:

```
var gulp        = require("gulp");
var browserify  = require("browserify");
var source      = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var tsify       = require("tsify");
gulp.task("ut", function () {
    return browserify({
        basedir: "./",
        debug: true,
        entries: "./src/main.ts",
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {}
    })
    .external("jquery")
    .plugin(tsify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source("./dist/bundle.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(env.gulp.browserify.outdir));
});
```

**Main.ts**

```
import { sayHello } from "./component/greet";
import { showHello } from "./component/greet";

showHello("greeting", "unit test source code");
```

Answer (score 1):

This simplest solution is to add the `common.js` file to Browserify's `entries` option:

```
return browserify({
    basedir: "./",
    debug: true,
    entries: [
        "./some/path/common.js",
        "./src/main.ts"
    ],
    cache: {},
    packageCache: {}
})
```